# Coldfusion WCF api implementation

Tags: wcf, coldfusion

Below is the example of calling API that I got from Provider, I am facing problem converting this code to coldfusion. Any help will be appriciated

```
    var parameters = new List<RegaloPayBillerFieldWithValue>
   {
    new RegaloPayBillerFieldWithValue
    {
      Name = "NPE",
      Value = "1234567890"
    }
  };
  var preReceipt = client.RegaloPayPreReceipt(accessId: "2FC60D63-9091-4530-BC08-AF0D5742BBF2", billerPublicId: 3, localAmount: 0, billParameters: parameters);
```

The part where I am facing the problem is the upper part i.e.

```
   var parameters = new List<RegaloPayBillerFieldWithValue>
   {
    new RegaloPayBillerFieldWithValue
    {
      Name = "NPE",
      Value = "1234567890"
    }
  };
```

Two variables here i.e. Name and value are not being posted correctly.Test url is http://regalocashservice.cloudapp.net:8085/RegaloCashService.svc?wsdl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write-

```
    <cfset wsdlurl = "http://regalocashservice.cloudapp.net:8085/RegaloCashService.svc?wsdl">
    <cfset parameters = StructNew()>
    <cfset RegaloPayBillerField = ArrayNew(1)>
    <cfset vars = structNew()>

    <cfset ArrayAppend(RegaloPayBillerField, {Name="NPE", Value="1234567890"})>
    <cfset StructAppend(parameters, {RegaloPayBillerFieldWithValue = RegaloPayBillerField })>
   <cfset vars["billerPublicId"] = 2>
   <cfset vars["localAmount"] = 0>
   <cfset vars["accessId"] = "2FC60D63-9091-4530-BC08-AF0D5742AAF2">

   <cfinvoke webservice="#wsdlurl#" method="RegaloPayPreReceipt" returnVariable="res" argumentcollection="#vars#" > 
<cfinvokeargument name="billParameters" value="#parameters#"/>
   </cfinvoke> 
   <cfdump var="#res.getResponseCode()#">
```

Comment: Unless I am missing something, this is essentially the same as [what I already suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24515183/104223), just in cfml form..

Comment: Leigh, Your code is working fine too and I upvoted it.

Comment: I was more curious why this was selected as the answer, since it is an adaptation of my earlier example. Thought maybe I omitted something.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>  var parameters = new List<RegaloPayBillerFieldWithValue>
>    {
>     new RegaloPayBillerFieldWithValue
>     {
>       Name = "NPE",
>       Value = "1234567890"
>     }
>   };
> ```

From the example, and [WSDL](http://regalocashservice.cloudapp.net:8085/RegaloCashService.svc?xsd=xsd3), it looks like they are just creating an array of structures, which is then passed via a wrapper object ie another structure.  I *think* it should work if you create the array, then wrap it like so:

```
<cfscript>
  // create ArrayOfRegaloPayBillerFieldWithValue wrapper object
  parameters = [ {Name="NPE", Value="1234567890"} ];
  billParameters  = { RegaloPayBillerFieldWithValue=parameters };

  // create web service
  ws = createObject("webservice", "http://regalocashservice.cloudapp.net:8085/RegaloCashService.svc?wsdl");
  // debug
  writeDump(ws);

  // get result code
  result = ws.RegaloPayPreReceipt( "2FC60D63-9091-4530-BC08-AF0D5742AAF2"
                                    , 3 , 0, billParameters  );
  writeDump(result.getResponseCode());
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: the code below was tested in CF 11 Dev Edition environment

```
<cftry>
  <cfset parameters = StructNew()>
  <cfset StructAppend(parameters, {Name="NPE", Value="1234567890"})>
  <cfinvoke webservice="test" method="RegaloPayPreReceipt" returnVariable="res"> 
    <cfinvokeargument name="accessId" value="REAL_ACCESSID_HERE"/> 
    <cfinvokeargument name="billerPublicId" value="3"/>
    <cfinvokeargument name="localAmount"    value="0"/>
    <cfinvokeargument name="billParameters" value="#parameters#"/>
  </cfinvoke> 
  <cfdump var="#res#">
  <cfcatch type="Any">
    <cfdump var="#cfcatch.message#">
  </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Web Service "test" is mapped to http://regalocashservice.cloudapp.net:8085/RegaloCashService.svc?wsdl in CF Admin Tool. Here is dump of the object returned *org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.domainclasses_dtos_results.RegaloPayPreReceiptResult*

[image]

Comment: Mr.Babrenok,Thanks for answering. I am also getting this but problem is with the response it shows i.e. unknown error occured when used         <cfdump var="#res.getResponseCode()#"> . I asked this to providers, They said two parameters name and value are not being posted correctly. They should be of type 'RegaloPayBillerFieldWithValue'.